# Passing an EditText Value as IntentExtra from a different Layout in AdapterView Issue

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm using a AdapterView for a ListView, the activity where we can find the list view and an EditText.

When we click on one element of the ListView we go to the second activity, and I want to send the data of the selected item as an extra in a intent.This data will then be shown in the EditText

I tried this code, but it doesn't seem to work, it shows always the default value of the EditText.

here is the code of the adapter view :

```js
public class adapterq extends ArrayAdapter<Questionaire> {
Bitmap image;


public adapterq(Context context, ArrayList<Questionaire> questionaires) {
   super(context, 0, questionaires);
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   
   final Questionaire c = getItem(position);    
   
   View  convertView2;
   if (convertView == null) {
      convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.customquest, parent, false);
      convertView2 = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_main, parent, false);
   }else{
    convertView2 = (View) convertView.getTag();
   }




   TextView q = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
   final EditText name =     (EditText) convertView2.findViewById(R.id.editText1);


   q.setText(c.getLabel()); 

   convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
 @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
      Intent intent = new Intent();
      intent.setClass(getContext(), Questions.class);
      intent.putExtra("name", name.getText().toString());
      intent.putExtra("category", c.getCode());
      getContext().startActivity(intent); 
      v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yourbackground);
      ((Activity) getContext()).overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_slide_in, R.anim.right_slide_out);
   
       

    }

    });
   convertView.setTag(convertView2);
   return convertView;
}

}
```

[image]

Comment: what values is set to editText `name`? and what are you doing inflatign 2 layouts in getView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [`ListView.setOnItemClickListener()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener(android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener)) instead. The callback returns what position in the list was clicked and the view. The position is used to retrieve the data object `Questionere`.
The `EditText` may be retrieved using a `findViewById()`.

```
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
         Questionaire item = list.getItemAtPosition(position);
         String name = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1)).getText().toString();
         Intent intent = new Intent();
         intent.setClass(getContext(), Questions.class);
         intent.putExtra("name", name);
         intent.putExtra("category", item.getCode());
         startActivity(intent); 
     } 
});
```

Comment: I should use that on the MainActivity ?? where I have both of the ListView and the EditText ? Right ?

Comment: Yea. Launching another activity from within the adapter is not ideal. You may use a member field reference to the EditText initialized in your onCreate() instead of looking it up every time the onItemClick is called.

Comment: Okay, I will test it and I will let you know, thanks